# Issue mapping field from a class to an object from a different database using springboot hibernate

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a `Flight` class which has an `Aircraft` and an `Operator` field. The `Flight` is stored in a local database for now, while the other two classes are stored in another database and they are managed by a different application. I've tried multiple approaches to mapping the aircraft and operator fields to the `Flight` class, but failed every time with different problems causing exceptions.

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(schema = "app2")
public class Flight implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "flight_sequence"
    )
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "flight_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    private String callsign;
    private Aircraft aircraft;
    private Date date;
    private Operator operator;
    private String origin;
    private Date offBlockTimeEst;
    private String destination;
    private Date arrivalTimeEst;
}
```

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(schema = "app1", indexes = @Index(name = "reg_index", columnList = "registration"))
public class Aircraft implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "aircraft_sequence"
    )
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "aircraft_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="operator_id", nullable=false)
    private Operator operator;
    private String registration;
}
```

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(schema = "app1")
public class Operator implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "operator_sequence"
    )
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "operator_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String country;
    private String email;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="operator")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Aircraft> aircrafts;
}
```

The database connection configurations are as follows:

```java
@Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:application.properties"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.user.project.repository.app2",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "app2EntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "app2TransactionManager")
public class App2DBConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Primary
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource app2DataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean app2EntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em
                = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(app2DataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(
                "com.user.project.domain.app2", "com.user.project.domain.app1");

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter
                = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
                env.getProperty("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto"));
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect",
                env.getProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect.storage_engine",
                env.getProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect.storage_engine"));
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        return em;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager app2TransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager
                = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(
                app2EntityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

```java
@Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:application.properties"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.user.project.repository.app1",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "app1EntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "app1TransactionManager")
public class App1DBConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.app1")
    public DataSource app1DataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean app1EntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em
                = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(app1DataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(
                "com.user.project.domain.app1");

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
                "none");
        properties.put("hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy", "org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy");
        properties.put("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy", "org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy");
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager app1TransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager
                = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(
                app1EntityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

If the `Flight` class is set up to store the whole `Aircraft` or `Operator` object in the database, then whenever I try to access fields of these two classes I get the following exception:
`org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException : could not initialize proxy – no Session`.

I've also tried adding a `@ManyToOne` and a `@JoinColumn(name="aircraft_id")` but I get the following exception: `object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing`. After trying to solve this by adding `cascade = CascadeType.ALL`, I get the following exception: `detached entity passed to persist` and it also created an aircraft and an operator table in the database which isn't ideal.

```java
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: com.user.project.domain.app1.Aircraft; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.user.project.domain.app1.Aircraft
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:297)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy132.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.user.project.parser.MessageParseService.parseMessage(MessageParseService.java:62)
    at com.user.project.parser.MessageParseService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$70b64fcd.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
    at com.user.project.parser.MessageParseService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6e9c298c.parseMessage(<generated>)
    at com.user.project.connector.QueueConnector.listen(QueueConnector.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor89.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:169)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:119)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:262)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandlerAndProcessResult(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:208)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:147)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1670)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1589)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1577)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1568)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1512)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:993)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:940)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:84)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1317)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1223)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.user.project.domain.app1.Aircraft
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:784)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:752)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$7.cascade(CascadingActions.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:510)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:434)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:427)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:264)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:760)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:746)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy120.persist(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:647)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:530)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:286)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:640)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    ... 41 more
```

A new `Flight` object is created in the `parseMessage` method, then saved in the database using a repository which extends JpaRepository:

```java
public void parseMessage(String message){
    //code which cleans up the message removed for simplicity
    Flight flight = createFlightFromMessage(message);
    flightRepository.save(flight);
}
    
private Flight createFlightFromMessage(String message) {
    //code which sets other fields removed for simplicity
    String registration = getRegistrationFromMessage(message);

    Aircraft aircraft = aircraftRepository.findAircraftByRegistration(registration);
    Operator operator = operatorRepository.findOperatorByCode(codePreviouslyExtractedFromMessage);

    return new Flight(..., aircraft, operator, ...);
}
```

```java
public interface FlightRepository extends JpaRepository<Flight, Long> {
}
```

```java
public interface AircraftRepository extends JpaRepository<Aircraft, Long> {
    Aircraft findAircraftByRegistration(String registration);
}
```

```java
public interface OperatorRepository extends JpaRepository<Operator, Long> {
    Operator findOperatorByCode(String code);
}
```

The `parseMessage` method is called from a `listen` method called from a queue connector:

```java
@Component
public class QueueConnector {
    @Autowired
    private MessageParseService messageParseService;

    @RabbitListener(queues = "myqueue")
    public void listen(String delivery) {
        String message = new String(delivery.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        try{
            messageParseService.parseMessage(message);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

What would be the correct approach to map the `Aircraft` and `Operator` which are managed in a different database by another application without getting any exceptions?

Comment: Please add the complete stacktrace

Comment: added stacktrace for the last error. also added that the cascade created an aircraft and an operator table to the local database which is not ideal

Comment: How do you store the objects. Can you share this code please

Comment: by using `flightRepository.save(flight);`, the repository extenting `JpaRepository`

Comment: Please show the code where you call it

Comment: added more code for better explanation

Comment: You cannot refrence entities from different JPA entitymanagerfactories. That simply won't work. If you want to store them in both you need to make a copy to store instead of storing the already existing entity into the other database (as that is attached to the other DB/entitymanager).

Comment: What other approach would where be to do that?